# has_many :through 4r post contributions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, has-many-through

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to setup the contributions controller and the form in the view. I've set some forms in the view so i know the join tables work.

As of right now a post belongs_to user && a user has_many posts

**Objective:**

1. user1 creates post - which belongs to user1

2. user2 requesting to join the user1_post as a contributor

3. user1 accepts or declines request

4. user2 is now a contributor to user1_post

5. user1 can remove user2 as a contributor

Got the has_many :through setup properly and have tested it in the console

**contribution.rb**

```
class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  def accept
    self.accepted = true
  end
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :contribution_requests, -> { where(accepted: false) }, class_name: 'Contribution'
  has_many :contributions, -> { where(accepted: true) }
  has_many :contributors, through: :contributions, source: :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :contribution_requests, -> { where(accepted: false) }, class_name: 'Contribution'
  has_many :contributions, -> { where(accepted: true) }
  has_many :contributed_posts, through: :contributions, source: :post
end
```

**contributions_controller.rb**

```
class ContributionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contribution = current_user.contributions.build(:user_id => params[:id])
    if @contribution.save
        flash[:notice] = "Added contributor."
        redirect_to posts_path(@post)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to add contributor."
        redirect_to posts_path(@post)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @contribution = current_user.contributions.find(params[:id])
    @contribution.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Removed contributor."
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without much context, this is what I'd do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :contributions, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> can use posts#edit to add extra contributions
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/contributions/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    # @post form 
<% end %>
## contributor add / remove form (select boxes) 

#app/controllers/contributions_controller.rb
class ContributionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @contribution = current_user.contributions.new contribution_params
      @contribution.post = @post

      notice = @contribution.save ? "Added Contributor" : "Unable to add contributor"
      redirect_to @post, notice: notice
   end

   def destroy
      @contribution = current_user.contributions.find params[:id]
      @contribution.destroy

      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Removed Contributor"
end

   private

   def contribution_params 
      params.require(:contribution).permit(:user, :post, :accepted)
   end
end
```

---

As an aside, you should look at an [ActiveRecordExtension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) to give you some methods for your `conbtributions` association (instead of having multiple associations):

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contributions, -> { extending ContributionExtension }
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contributions, -> { extending ContributionExtension }
end

#app/models/concerns/contribution_extension.rb
class ContributionExtension
   def requests(status=false)
     where accepted: status
   end

   def accepted(status=true)
     where accepted: status
   end
end

@post.contirbutions.requets
@post.contributions.accepted

@user.contributions.requests
@user.contributions.accepted
```

--

And also, you should look at implementing a [`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) for your `Contribution` model:

```
#app/models/contribution.rb
class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
   state_machine :accepted, initial: :pending do
      event :accept do
         transition [:pending, :denied] => :accepted
      end

      event :deny do
         transition [:pending, :accepted] => :denied
      end
   end
end
```

Great [article about it here](http://www.sitepoint.com/state-machines-in-ruby/).

This will allow you to call:

```
@contribution = current_user.contributions.find params[:id]
@contribution.accept
```

It will also give you several other cool methods:

```
@contribution.accepted?
@contribution.state
```

Comment: Never really used state machine - I'm trying to understand how I would setup a post request button in post-show.html - and how would the pending states be established - I'm guessing through if statements?

Comment: Post request button? Can you give some more context?

Comment: Ok so lets say manuel user1 creates a post which now belongs to me - rich = user2 will have to visit my post and click a **request button** to join the post as a contributor - once the request is sent and received by user1 he can view a list of requests in the post and accept or decline the requests

Comment: The state machine just adds a bunch of instance methods to your object. This way, you'll not need to declare `self.accept` - you'll be able to use `@post = Post.find x` `@post.accept` from the state machine itself

Comment: So creating the request in view : <%= form_for([@post, @post.contributions.accept]) do |f| %>
<% end %> : I may have to hold off on this setup for now - I'm confused.. thanks

Comment: Hang on. The state machine does NOTHING to your flow. It just gives you extra methods to use in the controller. If you use the state machine, you'll be able to get rid of the bullshit `def accept` method in your model, and use a state machine to handle it